# Why does the indicator function fulfill the random variable definition?

Tags: random-variables

Why does the indicator function fulfill the random variable definition?

Def. of random variable:
[Pre-image of random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258129/pre-image-of-random-variable?rq=1)

It's intuitive that the pre-image of $1_A=1, \omega \in A$ is in $F$. Since $A \in F$.

However, since $1_A=0$, when $\omega \not \in A$, then the pre-image of this would not belong to $F$? But it would need to, because of the def. of r.v.?

Comment: You probably mean $A\in F$ (not $A\subset F$).

Answer (score 2):

Function $\mathsf1_A$ can have at most $4$ distinct preimages:$$\varnothing, A, A^{\complement},\Omega$$where $\Omega$ denotes the whole space.

If $A\in\mathcal F$ then also $A^{\complement}\in\mathcal F$ since $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ is closed under complements.

In all cases we have $\varnothing,\Omega\in\mathcal F$.